# Is it possible to use Gradle as a build target in the SAM CLI?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I'm currently building a Java Lambda function as a Gradle project. The application is built using the command `gradlew build`. This both tests ad builds the application JAR.

The definition for my function resembles the following snippet from the SAM `template.yml`.

```
  ImageResizeLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: thumbor
      Handler: com.nosto.imagevector.resizer.ResizeController::handleRequest
      Runtime: java11
      Events:
        ResizeImage:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /quick/{accountId}/{thumbnailVersion}/{imageId}/{hash}/
            Method: GET
      Policies:
        S3ReadPolicy:
          BucketName: !Ref ImageBucket
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: makefile
```

As shown here, the build method is defined as `makefile`. The `Makefile` inside my Gradle project (which seems really) unnecessary has this bit:

```
CUR_DIR := $(abspath $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))))

build-ImageNormalizeLambda:
    cd $(CUR_DIR)/.. && ./gradlew normaliser:clean normaliser:buildZip
    cd $(CUR_DIR) && unzip build/distributions/normaliser.zip -d $(ARTIFACTS_DIR)
```

Because my project contains multiple projects, there's a Gradle subproject for every function.

While this seemingly works, I've glued this together and seems to add yet another DSL to the already-complex build.

Based on this project, I can see some work on a Gradle builder but I'm unsure how/if this transitive dependency is used. https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-builders/tree/develop/aws_lambda_builders/workflows/java_gradle

Is there a better way to build a Gradle-based Java Lambda function as compared to this approach? The documentation for `sam build` doesn't go very deep.

Comment: Found this, if it helps - 
https://linuxtut.com/en/b91097dc0c3697e16f07/

Comment: Just a very general remark: if you've many small functions you should perhaps consider bundling them in one gradle.